Can a state appoint Presidential electors from out-of-state to get around the difficulty of Presidents and VP's being from the same state?
The twelfth amendment to the United States constitution reads:

The Electors shall meet in their respective states and vote by ballot
for President and Vice-President, one of whom, at least, shall not be
an inhabitant of the same state with themselves;...

This is typically understood to effectively prevent the President and Vice-President being from the same State (since that State could not have its Electors vote for both of them).
But is there any constitutional restriction that prevents a State from appointing Electors who are inhabitants of a different State, or from State political parties nominating Electors from a different State? Or do the Electors have to be inhabitants of the State that appoints them?
Can this be used to get around the situation where a party wants to have Presidential and Vice-Presidential nominees from the same state on the same ticket?
Given that in modern times, Electors are expected to be nothing more than human rubber-stamping machines that uncritically vote in accordance with the State's popular vote, would anyone even care where the Electors reside?

Never been tried,  probably wouldn't be considered proper.  The intent of the drafters of the constitution seems clear, and only an extreme textualist would seen any ambiguity in how this clause should be read.

This Q is related to the Electors Appointment Clause which should be included for reference.

@JamesK I disagree that the intent seems clear, as least according to your interpretation. I see the intent of the constitution being to empower the Electors (rather than the States or the people) to choose who is to be President and Vice-President, and this particular clause to limit home-town bias in the Electors.

Well like I said, It's never been tried.  I've had a cursory look around to see if it had been suggested by anyone, and could find nothing.  Since the restriction is pretty easy for any serious candidate to circumvent, I can't imagine it ever being tested.  You're obviously the "extreme textualist" that I spoke of in my first comment!

There definitely seems an assumption that a state will appoint electors from that state, although it doesn't seem to be codified anywhere. There is also a bit of vagueness about what qualifies as coming from a state. So I'd expect it to be litigated if anyone tried it, but who knows?

I have to say, that absolutely will not work.  The rule is that an elector cannot vote for a ticket where both members are inhabitants of the same state that the elector represents.  That is the “plain meaning”, and as Prem points out, interpreting it any other way would have bizarre consequences.
You’d have much better luck having the VP candidate just move out of state four days before accepting the invitation to run.

Workarounds may not work:
I too am a "textualist", asx described by user James K, though I would be more "extreme" than normal.

"the Electors shall meet in their respective states and vote"

"is there any constitutional restriction that prevents a State from appointing Electors who are inhabitants of a different State"


When the State uses Electors from other States, those Electors shall have to meet in those other States.
Hence the trick/workaround/hack/guile to make President & Vice President from the same State will not work.
In other words, when President & Vice President are from State X which is trying to use the Electors from State Y, then:

Those Electors might be deemed to be from State X & can not vote for two candidates from the same State X
Those Electors might be deemed to be from State Y & shall meet in State Y

ADDENDUM :
There was a very relevant remark at Wikipedia. I have included it below, with my high-lighting, with no other changes.

This all changed on September 4, when the committee recommended that
the nation's chief executive be elected by an Electoral College, with
each state having a number of presidential electors equal to the sum
of that state's allocation of representatives and senators.
Recognizing that loyalty to one's individual state outweighed loyalty
to the new federation, the Constitution's framers assumed individual
electors would be inclined to choose a candidate from their own state
(a so-called "favorite son" candidate) over one from another state.
So they created the office of vice president and required the electors to vote for two candidates, at least one of whom must be from
outside the elector's state, believing that the second vote would be
cast for a candidate of national character. Additionally, to guard
against the possibility that electors might strategically waste their
second votes, it was specified that the first runner-up would become
vice president.
The resultant method of electing the president and vice president,
spelled out in Article II, Section 1, Clause 3, allocated to each
state a number of electors equal to the combined total of its Senate
and House of Representatives membership. Each elector was allowed to
vote for two people for president (rather than for both president and
vice president), but could not differentiate between their first and
second choice for the presidency.


Good job coming up with an argument on the same level of nitpickiness as the original question.

But "their state" needn't mean "their state of residence"; it could mean "the state that chose them as electors."

I am neither a Judge nor a Constitutional Expert , @phoog , but "the State that chose them" might not stand because ((1)) It should then read "Electors shall meet in the States they represent" ((2)) It would allow Common Electors between multiple States ((3)) It would allow choosing outsiders ( who could be even foreigners ) as Electors. Here "Electors belong to State" may avoid such issues.

One of the reasons SCOTUS is so often able to make decisions on ideological grounds is that the language of the Constitution is sloppy and can be interpreted however you want.

Where the language is sloppy , the SCOTUS may use the ideology/intent , @Barmar , hence here the intent of saying "at least one Candidate is out of State" clearly will favour that the "Electors represent a State & vote at least one Candidate out of State"

@Prem These days, partisanship is a more likely ground than "intent" in electoral matters.

Are you disagreeing with Barmar or with me , @ohwilleke , or with the wiki or with the "Constitutional History Experts" whose words are given in that wiki ?

@Prem I was responding to the language "Where the language is sloppy , the SCOTUS may use the ideology/intent" in your comment.

@ohwilleke I was thinking of how SCOTUS found a way to declare Obamacare constitutional by calling the individual mandate a tax, and the way different courts found ways to decide Roe and Dobbs in opposite ways. When the language is vague, courts can twist it to their desired results.

I was merely responding to Barmar who introduced SCOTUS here , @ohwilleke , where by I observed that , even with that being the case ( whether that is valid or not ) , my answer to OP might stand.

@Prem By the way, it is never correct to put a space between a punctuation mark and the word that comes before it. It is actually quite jarring and distracting to do so.
